# Twitter option was not showing in fabric plugin in android studio

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

Iam integrating twitter Login in android application in my Mac. I signup in fabric and installed fabric plugin in my android studio. again I login with my credentials,  But didn't find twitter option 
[image]

this is my screen shot of fabric plugin options. 
please some one help me

Answer (score 7):

Mike from Fabric here. Due to Google's acquisition of Fabric from Twitter, Twitter Kit is no longer available via Fabric. You should follow the instructions on their [developer site](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/installation).

**Edit** Twitter is also retiring their SDK effective October 31, 2018.